# Is there a way to determine the minimum version of PHP required to run a script automatically?

Tags: php, compatibility

I know of http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo - however I am looking for a online service that offers something similar, or perhaps better.

I have noticed that PHP_CompatInfo has not been updated in some time (2009-01-19)

I would like to be able to upload a set of files, or if needed, one at a time, and receive data back on what the expected minimum version of PHP is required to run those files.

Until now, I have simply scraped all functions from my files, and then done look-ups on php.net to see what version would be needed for example:

filter_var
(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

Comment: It might not be super current and complete, but PHP_CompatInfo can also detect some PHP 5.3 dependencies. And after all it might be easier to augment some rules than to write your own string match solution. (Bookmarking this, interesting question, but I doubt there is a better alternative.)

Answer (score 2):

[PHP_CompatInfo2](https://github.com/llaville/php-compat-info) is under development, see the [announcement](http://news.php.net/php.pear.dev/54204) on the PEAR developer list.

See http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/